# Can't call GameCenter in my Unity game for iOS

Tags: c#, game-engine, unity-game-engine, game-center-leaderboard

I'm trying to integrate Game Center into my Unity 5 project and facings troubles. It seems that authentification is OK when the game starts on iOS device, a notification appears, but leaderboard button does not work, nothing happens when I tap GC button. I assigned the initiation of "ShowLeaderboard()" to GC button. Please, take a look at the script I use below. Hope to find a resolution for my issue. Thank you in advance.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.GameCenter;
using System.Collections;

public class GameCenter : MonoBehaviour {

    public string leaderboardID = "mygameleaderboard";

    void Start () {
        AuthenticateToGameCenter();
    }

    private bool isAuthenticatedToGameCenter;
    public static void  AuthenticateToGameCenter() {
        #if UNITY_IPHONE
        Social.localUser.Authenticate(success => {
        if (success) {
            Debug.Log("Authentication successful");
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Authentication failed");
            }
        });
        #endif
    }

    public static void ReportScore(long score, string leaderboardID) {
        #if UNITY_IPHONE
        Debug.Log("Reporting score " + score + " on leaderboard " + leaderboardID);
        Social.ReportScore(score, leaderboardID, success => {
            if (success) {
            Debug.Log("Reported score successfully");
            } else {
                Debug.Log("Failed to report score");
                }
            });
        #endif
    }

    //call to show leaderboard
    public static void ShowLeaderboard() {
        #if UNITY_IPHONE
        Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
        #endif
    }
}
```

Comment: I personally use Prime31 plugins specifically for Unity and GameCenter Integration. It neatly places everything and abstracts from Social Platform with a nice interface. http://prime31.com

Answer (score 5):

To show the iOS Game Centre Leaderboard you need to use the [GameCenterPlatform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SocialPlatforms.GameCenter.GameCenterPlatform.html).

Your code would then be:

```
void ShowLeaderboard() {
    #if UNITY_IOS
    GameCenterPlatform.ShowLeaderboardUI(leaderboardId, UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.TimeScope.AllTime);
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Agreed, GameCenterPlatform is the latest and greatest. Social worked like a charm in Unity 4, but with 5 they are pushing people to use this API. I do however still use social with Google Play Games for iOS. It's really nice and easy to work with

Answer (score 0):

Actually now you even don't have to get GameCenterPlatforms. You can simply use `Social`. Like.

```
public void OnLeaderboard()
{
    // Checking if user already authenticated or not.
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
                Social.ShowAchievementsUI ();
            else
                // If not then authenticate first then show Leaderboard
                Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
                    // handle success or failure
                    if (success)
                        Social.ShowAchievementsUI ();
                });
        }
}
```